# Read local group policy using powershell commands

Tags: powershell

Iam unable to get Gpresult of local group policy using powershell. I need help on this to get the local gpo's on windows Server 2022

Answer (score 0):

not much you want to share with us about what you have tried. you could do:

```
#Export gpresult into xml
gpresult /x C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\gpo.xml
#Load xml
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.Load("C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\gpo.xml")
```

$xml contains the information.

Comment: Thank you for the brother I already done this before Brother. I need help on this to read local group policy on workgroup server

Comment: same game - my personal PC is also not a domain joined device and it works... so.... ```$xml.rsop.UserResults.domain = Local```